# django model inherit custom manager

Tags: django, django-models

I cannot make a django model inherit a custom manager from its parent class. I have done something like the following:

```
class baseclassmanager(models.Manager):
    """manager for baseclass"""

class baseclass(models.Model):
    """
    baseclass for subclass
    introspection shows this class has a manager of type baseclassmanager 
    """
    objects = baseclassmanager()

class subclass(baseclass):
    """
    subclass
    introspection shows this class has a manager of type models.Manager
    I want it to have a baseclassmanager manager
    """
```

I can only imagine that this has something to do with how the metaclass builds the model. Does anybody have a way make the subclass inherit the baseclass's manager? dit seems as if inheritance of managers would be a fairly desirable feature.

Your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance problem is solved by placing

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

in the base class.